# What is the forward compatibility of std::type_info in MSVC++?

Tags: visual-studio, dll, compatibility

I know we shouldn't mix code compiled with different versions of MSVC++, except when completely isolating the language run-time as with COM in-proc servers.

But some people think they can, and *forward* compatibility is not something you can guarantee years ahead of time.  In particular, the scheme used by this library (in 2006) to allow one DLL to work across callers with different compilation options and RTL dynamic/static selection worked because the dynamic library was always named `msvcrt.dll`.  That's not true now, so dealing with it is challenging.  But that's not the reason for posting.

Everyone thinks about heap functions (malloc, free, operator new, etc.) and the passing of pointers across the DLL boundary.  But I saw something else that is not being addressed at all.  Namely, the header file uses `std::type_info` to store typed values (similar to the locale facets, or Boost.Any), so the implicit assumption is that the caller (using VS10) can create instances of classes that contain `std::type_info` values, and the pre-build DLL (using some old version of the compiler) can understand them.

As I recall from looking at the implementation of `type_info` before, it uses inefficient string comparisons in order to work across linker boundaries.  But that just allows duplicate static constants to be seen as equivalent — it still requires that the underlying implementation of the type_info is the same!

So, **does anyone happen to know** if the implementation of the structures and interpretation of the fields therein have changed or are still the same, for different versions of the RTL as shipped by different versions of Visual Studio?  I'd like to hear about experiences either way, even if there is no definitive answer.

I also see the use of `std::string` in the header.  <sigh>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found out upon trying that the `std::string`, in a Debug build, *is not compatible* between Visual Studio 2005 (version 8) and VS 2010 (version 10).  The location of the data pointer is different, in particular.  So, a `std::string` created by VS2010 cannot be interpreted properly by code compiled with VS 2005.

I'm sure it's the same story for Release builds.  I recall that `std::string` in particular, unlike STL containers in general in Microsoft's library, are more intercompatible with certain run-time checking options, so it's not just the details of the compiler switches—though that is always an issue for compatibility even when the C++ compiler is the same version!

I didn't learn about `std::type_info`, but one such issue is sufficient to reject intercompatibility.

I'd like to point out for the wary that avoiding actually passing strings and using calls that are compatible at the ABI has a hidden gotcha:  **default arguments**.  The defaulted argument is constructed and passed automatically by the caller, and you might not be aware that such an optional argument is present when porting old code or whatnot.

Beware of DLLs that are opaque pre-built products, even if the business team finds it attractive for some reason.  Ten years later, “they” might not support the product anymore, and plans for forward compatibility will gradually fail as unexpected things change.